# Problem with asynchronous emit.events (Socket.io)

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, asynchronous, socket.io

I've got some problem with two asynchronous socket events in my socket.io server. Both are fired, when my Android-app sends an emit.event in the onCreate method.

I have read something about promises, but i dont really get it together with my code - i am pretty new to Javascript and asynchronous programming.

```
socket.on('getdata', function(){
  gpsdata.view('test', 'new-view', function(err, body){
  if(!err)
  {
    body.rows.forEach(function(doc){
      console.log(doc.value);
      socket.emit('getRouteNames', doc.value);
    });
  }
});
})
socket.on('getdata2', function(){
 gpsdata.view('test', 'data', function(err, body){
   if(!err)
   {
     console.log(body.rows[0].value);
     socket.emit('getFirstTrack', body.rows[0].value);
   }
 });
});
```

So the emit-events have to be synchronous.

I tried it like that now, but i did not work.

```
socket.on('getdata', function(){
  gpsdata.view('test', 'new-view', function(err, body){
  if(!err)
  {
    let promisefunc = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      body.rows.forEach(function(doc){
        console.log(doc.value);
        socket.emit('getRouteNames', doc.value);
      });
      resolve();
    });
    promisefunc.then(function(fromResolve){
      console.log(body.rows[0].value);
      socket.emit('getFirstTrack', body.rows[0].value);
    });
  }
});
})
```

Comment: is this related to android?

Comment: which events are you asking about? the ones you're handling or the ones you're emitting?

Comment: the ones i am emitting, well the client-side is in android so i just added the tag but the problem is on the server-side.